# Best way to search a netty ChannelBuffer for a string (without making a new string)?

Tags: java, netty

I have proxy server implemented using Netty in which I decode HTTP requests and then write these requests to an outgoing channel based on their path. I need to extract some information from the content of the HTTP request for some future processing (basically, find a substring of the form "request-id:" and record  for later use. What is the best way to do this? Obviously, I can dump the content of the channel buffer into a string and use standard java string searching techniques, but is there a straightforward and low-overhead way to do this in netty, without creating a new string? For example, if there were something like an `asCharSequence(CharSet)` method for ChannelBuffer, I could just use a java Pattern/Matcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bumped into this issue a while ago as I was trying to sniff the content type of the bytes contained within a ChannelBuffer.

It occurred to me that you might use:

```
channelBuffer.toByteBuffer().asCharBuffer()
```

which you could then pass to a regex Pattern.Matcher, since this will not re-allocate the buffer, rather it just gets wrapped and re-represented, as it were. But this doesn't work because the CharBuffer needs to be Charset.decoded, which is probably just as bad as converting the ChannelBuffer to a string.

One of the issues with [ChannelBufferIndexFinder](http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBufferIndexFinder.html) is that it tends to work best when searching for one specific byte, where as when you're searching for a String (or more basically a byte array of length > 1), I could not get it work the way I wanted.

I started work on this ChannelBufferIndexFinder implementation called [ByteSequenceIndexFinder](https://gist.github.com/nickman/5502143) which helps to find an actual sequence of bytes within a ChannelBuffer, but there's a couple of issues with it:

1. Because of the way [ChannelBuffer.bytesBefore(...)](http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer.html#bytesBefore%28org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBufferIndexFinder%29) works, it does not return the direct offset of the located array, but rather the end of it, so you have to subtract **byte array length +1** from the returned index to get the offset of the beginning of the byte sequence within the byte buffer.
2. Since the finder must keep state (the number of bytes matched so far), it's not thread safe. I tried replacing the simple state (of one int) with a ThreadLocal but the performance was drastically reduced, but it remains an option.

There's actually an alternate calling method which is non-standard that address issue #1 and it works like this:

```
ChannelBuffer bufferToSearch = ...;
String searchStr = "....";
ByteSequenceIndexFinder finder = new ByteSequenceIndexFinder(searchStr.getBytes());
int startingOffset = finder.findIn(bufferToSearch);
```

That startingOffset is the offset of the first byte of the matched byte sequence within the channel buffer.

Hopefully it might be helpful to you if you need something like this. [This](https://gist.github.com/nickman/5502615) is the beginnings of a test case for it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use ChannelBuffer.indexOf(...) and pass a ChannelBufferIndexFinder into the method ?

http://netty.io/3.6/api/org/jboss/netty/buffer/ChannelBuffer.html#indexOf(int,%20int,%20org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBufferIndexFinder)

Answer (score 0):

I am using following implementation of `ChannelBufferIndexFinder` to search for a string in `ChannelBuffer`:

```
public class StringFinder implements ChannelBufferIndexFinder {

    private String string;

    public StringFinder(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean find(ChannelBuffer buffer, int guessedIndex) {

        if (buffer.writerIndex() - guessedIndex < string.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        return string.equals(buffer.toString(guessedIndex,
                string.length(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
    }

}
```